# Workaround to use a method within a LINQ expression

Tags: c#, linq, exception

In my ASP.NET MVC3 application I have the following method that use **EF entities**:

```
public IQueryable<Products> GetCreatedProducts(int year)
{
        return GetAllProducts().Where(m => Equals(DateUtilities.ExtractYear(m.ProductCreationDate), year));
}
```

`ProductCreationDate` is a field stored in the **database** as string **"YYYYMMddhhmm"**.

`int DateUtilities.ExtractYear(string date)` is a method that I created in order to get the year from the string. Similarly I use `ExtractMonth` and `ExtractDay`.

However when I execute my application it launches an **NotSupported exception**:

*"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ExtractYear(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."*

By googling the problem I found out that it is a bug in **LINQ to Entities** Anybody knows a workaround?

Comment: A bug in LINQ to Entities? Is it a bug that it is unable to translate your function into SQL? To fix this insert a `.AsEnumerable()` before the `.Where()` clause but understand that you are pulling all products from the server to the client before doing the filtering.

Comment: @Martin, thanks. Exactly it cannot traslate the function to SQL. I cannot even populate the List otherwise I need to change all my Repository logic :-( Imagine having all those in-memory objects...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the exception because you work with `IQueryable`. Entity Framework will try to translate the predicate in the where clause into SQL but EF doesn't know how to translate your method.

If you don't want to (or can't) change the database you still have a few options:

1. Pull all rows to the client side and do the filtering on the client. You do this by changing from `IQueryable` to `IEnumerable`:

   ```
   return GetAllProducts()
     .AsEnumerable()
     .Where(m => Equals(DateUtilities.ExtractYear(m.ProductCreationDate), year))
     .AsQueryable();
   ```
2. To be more efficient you can use your own SQL (this requires EF 4.1 and only avoid pulling all products to the client, not the scan on the server):

   ```
   return context
     .Products
     .SqlQuery("select * from Products where substring(ProductCreationDate, 1, 4) = '2012'")
     .AsQueryable();
   ```

   Note that I was lazy and hardcoded the SQL. You should probably parametrize it and make sure you avoid any SQL injection attacks.

Comment: thanks. One last thing, converting the result to asEnumerable will populate the object?

Comment: @CiccioMiami: Everything is still lazy evaluated, but EF will no longer try to create SQL for you. Instead, when you iterate what is returned by `GetCreatedProducts` it will go back and call `GetAllProducts`, and then only return those that match the `Where` predicate, all done in lazy fashion as you move your iterator forward. However, the `Where` is evaluated client-side meaning that all products are instantiated. Those you don't keep around will be eligble for garbage collection when that happens.

Answer (score 4):

My first question would be why are you storing a date in the database as a string? Store it as a date and use data comparison against it through Linq.

The issue that you're coming up against is Linq doesn't understand what the method ExtractYear is when it tries to compile your Linq statement to raw SQL

**EDIT**
Another alternative would be to create a view in the database and query against the view with a computed column that represents the string value as a datetime.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I didn't create the database and I cannot modify any of the field. I am not a masochist :-D

Comment: you have no access to change the database? you could create a new field that was at least a computed column that you could use to query against. Trying to do any lookups on this column is going to be painfully slow since it will always do a table scan (or index scan if you index the column)

Comment: I have no right to touch the database. They told me the old ASP.NET Web Forms application was working smooth with that database. I didn't know LINQ had such drawback

Comment: that's too bad. The previous developer has left you in a pretty rough spot. As the database size grows, you'll start to feel performance issues as each time this query is run, it'll have to scan the entire table. I would state a case to management somewhere that you should change at least that one field. It'd be as simple as creating a temp column, selecting the data from the old to the new, deleting the old column and renaming the new

Comment: thanks, I needed to show a prototype within this week, everything is almost complete I didn't know I would face such issue...damn

Answer (score 4):

In this case you could go the other way:

```
GetAllProducts().Where(m => m.ProductCreationDate.StartsWith(year.ToString()));
```

Rather than extract the year from the string, find all strings beginning with the year you're after.

I'm not sure if these will work for the Month and Day searches:

```
var monthString = String.Format("{0:00}", month);
GetAllProducts().Where(m => m.ProductCreationDate.Substring(4,2) == monthString);  

var dayString = String.Format("{0:00}", day);
GetAllProducts().Where(m => m.ProductCreationDate.Substring(6,2) == dayString);
```

Comment: thanks this works for the year, but I need it also for the day and for the month

Comment: this just seems gross, not from an answer standpoint, but from a performance standpoint. running this query will be very slow as it will have to hit every single row in the table. If you were to index the column, it'd still be slow as it'd be doing an index scan

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is really a bug so much as a limitation -- there's no SQL version of `ExtractYear`, so it's not possible to execute this query.

You'll have to rewrite the query to either use only SQL-compatible commands (like some other answers have shown) or pull lots of data out of the database and do the filtering with LINQ-to-Objects (this could potentially be very expensive, depending on what you're querying and how many of the records match).

Answer (score 1):

You could do the extraction inline, something like this:

```
public IQueryable<Products> GetCreatedProducts(int year)
{
        string sYear = year.ToString();
        return GetAllProducts().Where(m => m.ProductCreationDate.Substring(0,4) == sYear);
}
```

Comment: I've edited the code, this should work I believe.  At the core, @HenryJackson is right.

Comment: thanks, you saved me. However it is a shame you cannot use method within a LINQ statements, Microsoft guys should fix this

Comment: sorry, I have to remove the answer. Your code launches a new exception *Unable to cast the type 'System.Nullable`1' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types.*